# Display project folder path in the terminal with Gulp-Notify instead of entire path of project on hard drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, gulp, gulp-notify

I am using [gulp-notify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-notify) to display extra information in the terminal when a task is run. Currently I can only get the full path on my HD and file name. I would prefer to only display the project folders as it is cleaner.

```
function copyVideo (done) {
   // Locate files
   return gulp.src('./src/assets/video/*')
   // Copy the files to the dist folder
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/video'))
   // Notify the files copied in the terminal
   .pipe(notify('Copied <%= file.relative %> to <%= file.path %>')),
 done();
}
```

Terminal view

[image]

I would like the terminal to simply say *Copied quick-scope-for-6.mp4 to \dist\assets\video*

I have tried <%= folder.path %> and <%= directory.path %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the form of `notify(Function)` (as documented [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-notify#notifyfunction)),
you can use the built-in [`path.relative`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to) method to get the destination path relative to your project folder.

```js
var path = require('path');
// ...

function copyVideo (done) {
  // Locate files
  return gulp.src('./src/assets/video/*')
  // Copy the files to the dist folder
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/video'))
  // Notify the files copied in the terminal
  .pipe(notify(file => {
    var destFolder = path.dirname(file.path);
    var projectFolder = path.dirname(module.id); // Also available as `module.path`
    return `Copied ${file.relative} to ${path.relative(projectFolder, destFolder)}`;
  })),
  done();
}
```

Comment: Hi Avraham, I can confirm that the gulp-notify output was "gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Copied quick-scope-for-6.mp4 to dist\assets\video". This solution worked perfectly and is exactly the result i required. Thanks!!